# How to manipulate a Jenkins Parameter (String) for use in Post-build Actions?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using a [parameterized build](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) on a *Jenkins 2.14* installation, meaning the user can trigger the build with the desired parameters. I have a *choice parameter* with the name - let's say `MYPARAMETER`. Now I can of course use this string variable in *Post-build action input fields* like `${MYPARAMETER}`.

In this choice there are lower case values for the user to choose from. In one specific input field (in a *Post-build action*) I need the same variable value, but with the difference that the first letter needs to be in upper case (due to case sensitivity in a path).

Is there a way to manipulate the existing variable? As a dirty fix I have currently a second *choice parameter* with the same values only different in capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

```
MYPARAMETER="abc"
echo ${MYPARAMETER^}
Abc
```

Using ^ will convert the first character to upper case. ^^ will convert all characters

Comment: you mean to put the variable declaration/initialization in the "Execute shell" text area, right? The problem is that I don't need to access the variable in this execution part, but to use it in a Post-build action input field. And variables declared in "Execute shell" are not available there, or I'm doing something the wrong way

Comment: just tried. Accessing the variable like ${MYPARAMETER^} directly in the input field (from the choice parameter) is not interpreted. THX anyways

Comment: This neither works in the `Execute shell` section nor within the Jenkins variable fields either. When attempting to do it from the shell, the build will error out, and when trying to do it via Jenkins, it treats it as a literal string instead a modified Jenkins variable.